# Xcode 12 update breaks Pods and Products

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, xcode12, grdb

I just updated Xcode to version 12. When I open up a previously working project I now get an error `No such module 'GRDB'`. I have tried deintegrating and reinstalling the Pods, cleaning the build folder, and restarting Xcode. Additionally, when I look under my Pods the Products and Frameworks are colored red (view picture).[image]

Comment: The red means the frameworks are missing. So it appears they need to be rebuilt. — When I get into this situation, I deintegrate and start over. Did you try that?

Comment: @matt I tried to deintegrate and reinstall pods, this did not have and effect.

Comment: did you "build" after that?

Comment: @bshirley Yes. After doing the deintegrate I cleaned the build folder and then rebuilt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One observation: This issue only appears when building for the Simulator, building for the device works fine.

I go to build settings and find the problem my Architectures is **arm64**: [image]

and I change to **Standard architectures** for every target in my Pods project : [image]

Answer (score 0):

I came across a "solution". I am not sure why this fixed the problem but when I was running into build issues, I was building for an iOS simulator. If I change the build to "Any iOS Device (arm64)" or to my iPhone then the issue goes away.